# graphviz automatic compilation

Tags: graphics, latexmk, dot2tex

With this file, `test.tex`:

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[pdf]{graphviz}

\begin{document}
   \digraph{abc}{
      rankdir=LR;
      a -> b -> c;
   }
\end{document}
```

And this `~/.latexmkrc`

```
$out_dir = 'build';
$pdf_mode = 1;
$pdf_previewer = 'zathura';
set_tex_cmds('-synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %O %S');
```

Running, `latexmk test.tex` generates

[image]

It seems as though the graphviz package does not work when a `build` directory is specified, even though it outputs a `abc.dot` to the `build` directory.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. With your rc file, latexmk does exactly what it is expected to. Do any of the files in the build directory contain messages indicating what the problem is? What does the command `which dot` say? Is graphviz properly installed?

Comment: are you sure you're using the $out_dir definition? my dot command is `/usr/bin/dot`

Comment: Here is the error...it can't find `abc.dot`
```
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))Error: dot: can't open abc.dot: No such file or directory
system returned with code 512
```

Comment: does your build directory have `abc.pdf`, which the build process should output? in `test.log` it doesn't report any errors but attempts to execute `runsystem(dot -Tpdf -o abc.pdf abc.dot)...executed.` which I can only assume is run from the directory with the tex file in it, not the build directory...

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I had a spurious `abc.pdf` around from my first manual tests. Once I delete it, I have the problem that you describe.

Comment: I just wrote an email to the maintainer of `latexmk`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the solution proposed by John Collins (maintainer of `latexmk`) in a recent email to me.

Put the following lines into the rc file for `latexmk`; let's call it `latexmkrc-graphviz`:

```
$out_dir = 'build';
$pdf_mode = 1;
set_tex_cmds('%O %S');

# Use internal latexmk variable to find the names of the pdf file(s)
# to be created by dot.
push @file_not_found, 'runsystem\(dot -Tpdf -o ([^ ]+) ';

add_cus_dep( 'dot', 'pdf', 0, 'dottopdf' );
sub dottopdf {
   system( "dot", "-Tpdf", "-o", "$_[0].pdf", "$_[0].dot" );
}
```

Let `test.tex` be the (slightly modified) MWE of the original post.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{graphviz}
\begin{document}
    \digraph{abc}{
       rankdir=LR;
       a -> b -> c;
    }
\end{document}
```

Then the command `latexmk -r latexmkrc-graphviz test` will create a sub-directory `build`, call `/usr/bin/dot`, and generate `test.pdf` in the build directory. Note that `--shell-escape` is not used. As a consequence, compilation cycles tend to be faster, as the rather slow `dot` command is only called when the contents of `\digraph` changes.

`build/test.pdf`:

[image]